# Google Cloud Bucket custom metadata set but not returned in the HTTP request

Tags: google-cloud-storage, httprequest, metadata

I've managed to add custom metadata to my public file stored in Google Cloud Bucket, but that custom header is not returned in the HTTP response.

The image below shows that my custom metadata (X-Content-Type-Options) was added to my object. When I request that file from my browser, this custom header is not part of the response.

[image: Google Object metadata]

Comment: You want the metadata when you serve the file with Storage into a browser (for downloading/viewing the file, url starting with `https://storage.cloud.google.com/...`) or when requesting the storage API (url starting with `https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1...`)?

Comment: When I request the file from the browser (`https://storage.cloud.google.com`).

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to add custom headers, but they will be prefixed with `x-goog-meta-`. AWS S3 suffers from the same limitation. It seems that this is due to security reasons. The leanest solution I've found to overcome this limitation is to use an edge such as AWS Lambda Edge or Cloudflare Edge Workers. The idea is to rewrite the headers on the fly. In my case, that would mean catching all headers that start with `x-goog-meta-`, and removing that prefix.

Here is an article of somebody who did that with AWS Lambda Edge: https://medium.com/@tom.cook/edge-lambda-cloudfront-custom-headers-3d134a2c18a2

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `x-goog-meta-` for setting the metadata to the object [(some examples here for adding a single metadata or for adding it in a `cp` operation)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata#custom-metadata).

You can get the custom metadata with the `gsutil` command and the `-L` param. You can also recover the custom metadata with the HTTP request API [(try it out here)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get).

But the custom metadata aren't provided in your browser when you access to the object via the URL `https://storage.cloud.google.com/...`. You have to build a proxy which requests the object with Storage API (for getting the content and the custom metadata) and which provides the object with the expected metadata.